# Group Scanner - GetQADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, quest

I'm trying to loop through all groups on a specific domain and for each group perform a validation in the number of members, if some group exceeds the threshold then flag it and build a report.

I guess I should get all members and then perform the validation but I'm stuck on this, for example, Get-QADGroupMember can look into all groups or you have to enter a specific group?

If I try with a specific group, for example,

```
$a = Get-QADGroupMember 'localcontoso.com\Administrators'
```

I'm getting,

```
Get-QADGroupMember : Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity: 'localcontoso.com\Administrators'.
```

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following one-liner you don't have to mess with the format of the group Identity. It get all groups, count threshold members and output only the groups with member count greater than the value specified in $threshold

```
Get-QADGroup -SizeLimit 0 | 
Where-Object { (Get-QADGroupMember $_ | Measure-Object).Count -gt $threshold }
```

Comment: a little short: `...(Get-QADGroupMember $_ ).Count...`

Comment: Yep, but that wont give you a zero if the group is empty, and casting it to array may be less efficient than measure-object.

Comment: doesn't an empty groups -gt (any value > 0 ) return false anyway?

Comment: I guess so, I was also trying to demonstrate the use of measure-Object

Comment: ha.. Ok. I was just curious why you used `measure-object`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you query AD from the same domain machine:

```
$a = Get-QADGroupMember 'localcontoso.com/builtin/Administrators'
```

or

```
$a = Get-QADGroupMember Administrators
```

If you query from a different domain:

```
$a = Get-QADGroupMember administrators -Service DomainControllerName -credential (get-credential)
```

note: `-credential`  may not be required

Comment: I was missing the Service parameter. Thanks